# How to get firebase storage image url to firestore database

Tags: database, flutter, file-upload, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload images to firebase storage and use that image url as metadata in firestore, however the image url is always null. Here is the codes

how I get the picture

```
File noticepic;
Future getNotice()async{
var tempImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
setState(() {
  noticepic=tempImage ;
});
}
```

how I upload it to firebase storage

```
uploadNotice()async{
  var randomno=Random(25);
  final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef=FirebaseStorage.instance
  .ref().child('cisnotices/${randomno.nextInt(5000).toString()}.jpg');
    StorageUploadTask task = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(noticepic);
    StorageTaskSnapshot snapshottask =  await task.onComplete;
   String downloadUrl = await snapshottask.ref.getDownloadURL();
    noticeProvider.changePhotoUrl(downloadUrl.toString());

  setState(() {
    print('pic uploaded');

  });

}
  NoticeProvider noticeProvider=NoticeProvider();
```

This is the noticeprovider.dart

```
 changePhotoUrl(String value){
 _photoUrl=value;
 notifyListeners();
   }

  saveNotice(){
 var newNotice=Notice(userName: userName,userPost: userPost,photoUrl: photoUrl,
 date: date,noticeId: uuid.v4());
 firestoreService.saveNotice(newNotice);
 }
```

how i trigger the picture to be taken by pressing a icon button

```
 child: IconButton(
                       icon: Icon(Icons.add_photo_alternate),
                       color: Colors.grey[700],
                            iconSize: 40,
                            onPressed:(){
                              getNotice().then((f) async => await uploadNotice());

                             }
                             ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can used this function for upload image and get url from firebase

```
Future uploadFile(File file) async {
    StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(
        '${FirebaseStorageFolder.transactionDoc}/${Path.basename(file.path)}}');
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(file);

    var dowurl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    print("done");
    return dowurl.toString();


  }
```